# ACF Google map sometimes not loading properly, throws "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF for google Maps on my WordPress website. Sometimes it works fine but mostly the map is not rendering after the page load and the console is throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at initMap ((index):616)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):1178)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
    at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1176)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
```

[image: Google is not defined error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody got stuck with the same issue, it worked for me when I changed `document.ready` to `window.load`. In the official ACF documentation, its `document.ready`

[image]"

Comment: Saved a lot of time, thanks ;) I was facing the same issue because using WP Complianz plugin (GDPR), the map didn't load. This trick fixed the issue.

Comment: glad to know it helped someone :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a map key.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

If it exists then make sure that it is in the header.

Comment: Thanks for the response Maulik. the map key is already added. the issue got fixed when i changed map initialization from "document.ready" to "window.load".